# Filtering Apostrophes (special characters) in UISearchBar - Swift, Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I currently have a UISearchBar that works fine, however, I've noticed that when entering apostrophes in the searchBar it does not return any results. **For example:** If I have a String: **Bob's** if  I search **Bob** it returns said string, however, as soon as I enter the apostrophe in the searchBar: **Bob'** the searchBar returns no results.

I've searched online for solutions, however, have not found anything that works. Any response would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

UISearchBar Code:

```
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        filteredData = data
    } else {
        filteredData = data.filter{$0.title.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

}

Struct:

```
struct Category {
    let title: String

    let items: [String]
}
```

Array:
`Category(title: "Bob's ", items: ["Data: xxx", "Data: xxx", "Data: xxx",]),`

cellForRowAt Func:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

        let title = filteredData[indexPath.row].title

          cell.myLabel.text = title

          cell.myImg.image = UIImage(named: title + ".png")

          return cell

    }

}
```

**Output returned in console when apostrophe is typed in searchBar:**
filteredData = []

Comment: That's because you do not have anyone with the title "Bob's" in your array, the search itself is working as expected. Execute `print("Bob's".range(of: "Bob'", options: .caseInsensitive) != nil)` in a playground and see for yourself.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the lack of information. I have edited my post to include more information. The issue is not with "Bob's" not being in the array, which you will see above.

Comment: I am not sure what the new code adds to the question really. Are you saying UISearchBar is broken or? Maybe try to debug or add a `print(filteredData)` directly after you have done the filtering.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. What I'm essentially saying is that the UISearchBar is not filtering apostrophes, and I have no idea why. Besides that, the UISearchBar works well. Let me know what else I can provide to further assist in helping this question get resolved

Comment: I have added a print statement as recommended, and when I type an apostrophe the output that is returned is: filteredData []

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved. It turns out there are variations of apostrophes. There is the U+0027 (') and the U+2019 (’). The U+2019 (’) is the default apostrophe on the iPhone and works with the UISearchBar code above. Hopefully, this helps anyone who has the same issue as me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the same issue by changing the Text input traits in Storyboard for the UISearchBar as below. Hope this helps

[image]